# Floating nav bar that stops fixed to the top of the page

Tags: javascript, floating, nav

I am trying to mimic something that I have seen a few different times. There is usually a banner with a nav bar below and when the page is scrolled it moves until it touches the top then stops and stays fixed. I am not completely sure how to accomplish this. I have seen a few different things that just dont work.

After looking around I figured out it will work something like this but I can seem to get it to work. I think I am missing some stuff

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
    #Table_01 {
        position:relative;
        left:0px;
        top:0px;
        width:1020px;
        height:854px;
        text-align: left;
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-left: auto;
    }
    body {
        font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
        font-size: 12px;
        color: #a4c639;
        text-align: center;
        margin: 0px;
    }
-->
</style>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    var topPos = 120;
    var updatedPos;
    window.onscroll = navPos;
    if (!topPos) {
        topPos = 120;
    }
    function navPos() {
        var pos = window.scrollY;
        if (!topPos) {
            topPos = 120;
        }
        var st = document.getElementById('navTest');
        if (st) {
            if (pos < topPos && updatedPos != 'absolute') {
                st.style.position = 'absolute';
                st.style.top = topPos + 'px';
                updatedPos = 'absolute';
                //alert('Switched to absolute');
            } else if (pos >= topPos && updatedPos != 'fixed') {
                st.style.position = 'fixed';
                st.style.top = '0'; 
                updatedPos = 'fixed';
                //alert('Switched to fixed');
            }
        }
    }
    navPos();
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="Table_01">
        <div id='navTest' style='position:absolute;z-index:999;top:120px;left:0; height:50px;width:100%; background-color:#000;' width='100%'>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have never used that, but I will try

Comment: Its easy just paste your code into the boxes click save and share the link

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/cbouwkamp/qyEMX/ here is the link and I posted it above also

Comment: Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/YYzVq/embedded/result/ ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/cbouwkamp/qyEMX/embedded/result/  ??

Comment: What is topPos equal to?

Comment: @MichaelSazonov That actually was the problem I dont know how I missed that. Probably from working on it for so long I just skipped over it. Thanks

Comment: Good [EXAMPLE](https://jsbin.com/ruhiji/3/edit?html,css,js,output)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All references to a non-existant `navTopPos` variable should be changed to reference the `topPos` variable. Your JS code should now be:

```
var topPos;
var updatedPos;
window.onscroll = navPos;
if (!topPos) {
    topPos = 120;
}
function navPos() {
    var pos = window.scrollY;
    if (!topPos) {//this line was changed
        topPos = 120;//this line was changed
    }
    var st = document.getElementById('navTest');

    if (st) {
        if (pos < topPos && updatedPos != 'absolute') {
            st.style.position = 'absolute';
            st.style.top = topPos + 'px';//this line was changed
            updatedPos = 'absolute';
            //alert('Switched to absolute');
        } else if (pos >= topPos && updatedPos != 'fixed') {
            st.style.position = 'fixed';
            st.style.top = '0';    
            updatedPos = 'fixed';
            //alert('Switched to fixed');
        }
    }
}
navPos();
```

The interpreter died somewhere here:

```
if (!topNavPos) {
    topNavPos = 120;
}
```

---

​
[Updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qyEMX/2/) with the necessary changes.

Comment: Sorry I didnt edit my code back correctly after changing it bunches of times but I figured out what was wrong

Comment: @shinjuo Happens the best of us. Could you accept this? It'll help anyone who comes across this question in the future.

Comment: Yes but i found out the main problem was I didnt set topPos to anything. Once set to 120 it works great

Comment: @shinjuo Yes. The current code now does that. And yes, it looks good :)

Comment: After moved to bottom, if i scroll to top - it doesn't go back!