# css: floating nav bar that fixes when touching the top

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I'm looking for ways to make this happen:

A nav bar that is put into a page normally and when it touches the top as I scroll, it fixes there.

You can take this in another way: it's like a fixed nav bar that was not put at the top at first.

It's something like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9346557/floating-nav-bar-that-stops-fixed-to-the-top-of-the-page) where the guy was using js but I want a more easy solution.

I'm using bootstrap and is it possible to use pure css to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using bootstrap, why not just the ["Affix"](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#affix) component that is built in?

To more properly answer your question though, no, there isn't a way to do this with CSS alone.  Reason being is that CSS is not capable of monitoring scroll position.  With javascript its as simple as adding a listener to scroll position of the window, and toggling a class that has a fixed position when it gets to "x" pixels.